# initialize const vector with const initializer list

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    typedef const std::vector<const int> set_t;
    set_t Low = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18};

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling the above code I got trillion of errors from STL headers.

What I want to do here is to initialize a vector and ensure that values can not be changed at some point later and also to make sure that no new values can be added.

This vector should be created once with initial values and not changed in any way.

What's wrong here?

Comment: `const int` is not a valid type. Elements need to be moved around.

Comment: if the size if fixed and known at compile-time, you can use `std::array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also a const vector, and it will let your code compile.

```
typedef const std::vector<int> set_t;
```

Making the `std::vector` alone *`const`* will expose only the non-modifying interface.  Your `int`s will not change.